# Bash's vim mode, not vi

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I was fascinated when I discovered vi-like bash's editing mode. One can easily toggle it by issuing `set -o vi` command. But is there any way to toggle vim-like mode?

I mean when you are in a vi-like mode you can press `v` key and edit your commands in a fully functional vi editor's window but I would like to know how to force bash to start `vim` editor instead of `vi` because of the perks `vim` provides us (visual selection, additional commands etc)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you set `EDITOR` variable, in bash you can press `Ctrl-x ctrl-e` to edit your current command line in your `EDITOR` e.g. `vim`

### EDIT

the `ctrl-x ctrl-e` is for emacs mode commandline editing, which is the default one. If you have already set it to vi mode, you could do what you have said, pressing the `v`. If you want to open the cmd line in vim, you have to set the `EDITOR` variable (in your .bashrc for example)

Personally I edit command line in emacs mode, even though vim is my main (and only) editor.

Comment: +1 pro tip: you can use `<c-x><c-f>` to complete filename inside of vim

Comment: How do you exit the editor without it running the command when you exit?

Comment: @trusktr here (zsh) I save and quit (:wq), the cmd will be fed on the command line  without getting executed and waiting for my "Enter"

Comment: @Kent Sounds nice. Bash is executing it after :wq

Answer (score 11):

In your `.bashrc`, put the following line:

```
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim
```

If you want `vim` in many other contexts too, such as in `git`, you should also set `EDITOR`:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: And of course, this only applies to the editor invoked with `v` or `C-x C-e`. It does not allow you to use additional, vim-specific key bindings on the bash shell prompt.

Comment: @thatotherguy, I thought the OP specifically asked how to force bash to start `vim` instead of `vi` when he hits `v`.