# Bash: Vim mode instead of vi mode

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I noticed when in vi mode in Bash (i.e., the mode enabled with "set -o vi"), that some commands, such as "diw", that work in Vim, but not in vi, don't work on the Bash command line. Is there an easy way to configure Bash so that its keybindings will support Vim commands?

I would like to be able to enter Vim commands on the command line without having to actually start the Vim program, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230990/bashs-vim-mode-not-vi).

Comment: `bash` doesn't support `vi` or `vim` commands; rather, it has keybindings similar to `vi`'s bindings for its own command set.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of doing this that I know of would be to use [Athame](https://github.com/ardagnir/athame).
It can be a surprisingly powerful experience in some cases. I particularly like it for interacting with a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop).

> Athame patches your shell to add full Vim support by routing your keystrokes through an actual Vim process. Athame can currently be used to patch readline (used by bash, gdb, python, etc) and/or zsh (which doesn't use readline).

[image]

Alternatively, I find [Spacemacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacemacs) with the eshell to be a reasonably functional, if strange, solution.

Comment: If this is the kind of answer the question is looking for, then that question is off-topic (from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in the "some questions are still off-topic" list, note the "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, or other off-site resource" entry).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't believe that makes it of topic. Here is looking for a solution to his problem. One potential solution is this tool. He is not specifically looking for tools.

Comment: Granted. The more compelling reason the question is off-topic is that it isn't about writing code, developing scripts, or otherwise unique to software development (as specified behind the above link), but is instead about *interactive* shell configuration and use -- a topic for [unix.se] SE or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 3):

First, the "vi mode" you get with `set -o vi` is not vi itself. It's an incomplete approximation of vi's behavior built into readline, the command-line editing library used by bash under the hood.

Second, because it is incomplete there's no reason whatsoever to expect *every* vi command to work.

Third, no, there's no "vim mode" so even less reason to expect *any* vim commands to work.

Fourth, if you absolutely want to edit the current command-line with Vim-like commands, why don't you go all the way and… actually use Vim:

```
<C-x><C-e>
```

That said, `$ man readline` tells you everything you need to customize its behavior and add bindings.

Comment: If you're already in `vi` mode, then the equivalent of `<C-x><C-e>` is `ESC`+`v`.

Answer (score 3):

Teach vi-command-mode `diw` to any software that uses readline (such as Bash) by adding this to your *~/.inputrc* file:

```
set keymap vi-command
"diw": "bde"
```

Comment: Would you please educate me? Short search didn't gave meaning to this. Thanks

Comment: Read https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax under the heading “Key Bindings”. TL;DR: that config line tells readline to interpret the key sequence “diw” as though you had typed “bde“ (go to start of word, delete to end of word)

Comment: Thanks a lot Luke. Have a nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ble.sh](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh). Which is a command line editor written in pure Bash which replaces the default GNU Readline. I like to call it "zsh for bash".

Appart from vim-style navigation it gives you:

- Enhanced completion
- Syntax highlighting
- [Other interesting features](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh#features)

After installation don't forget to add (recommended) to your `.bashrc`:

```
# at the start of your .bashrc file
[[ $- == *i* ]] && source /usr/share/blesh/ble.sh --noattach

...

#for vim-style mode
set -o vi

...

#at the end of your .bashrc file
[[ ${BLE_VERSION-} ]] && ble-attach
```

or you can just:

```
# at the start of your .bashrc file
source /usr/share/blesh/ble.sh
```

but this may not work as expected - [read this](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/discussions/254#discussioncomment-4284757).

Comment: Thanks, it is what I set but I don't know how to get rid of --INSERT--. Anyone has a idea how to do it?

Comment: Oh never mind, I found the solution is to create `.blerc` and put in something from [here](https://github.com/akinomyoga/blesh-contrib#pencil-contribprompt-vim-mode)